# Memoryleak Leak Issue

Tags: java

I checked all my Connection are closed properly.still am getting  java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space.why I am getting OutOfMemoryError.can you please suggest what I need to check.Is there any way to resolve without increase heap size.
I dint have chance to increas heap.please provide any solution

```
2013-01-18 02:42:11,487|INFO||GatewayOutboundPollerDaemon|Begin pollGatewayIncident().
2013-01-18 02:42:32,225|INFO||GatewayOutboundPollerDbHelper|Begin submitPendingRecords().
2013-01-18 02:42:54,565|INFO||GatewayOutboundPollerDbHelper|Query for Pending Records : SELECT TR_GATEWAY_RECORD_ID, decode(TR_TRANSACTION_TY
PE,1,'Update','Create')TR_TRANSACTION_TYPE, TR_GATEWAY_RECORD_STATUS FROM TM4530_INCIDENT_GATEWAY WHERE TR_GATEWAY_RECORD_STATUS = 0 AND TR_F
ROM_PARTNER = 'RAM' AND TR_GATEWAY_RECORD_STATE = 0 AND TR_TRANSACTION_METHOD = 1 FOR UPDATE
2013-01-18 02:49:47,527|ERROR||DaemonExecutor|ExecutableDaemon threw an exception:
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to check which objects are using the most memory e.g.

```
jmap -histo:live {pid} | head -30
```

At a guess you could be forgetting to close all you JDBC resources which will accumulate if your don't.

Answer (score 1):

From the logs, it looks like your are doing SQL select

How large is the resultset that you are querying out? If its returning a huge data set which consumes memory, then it can result in OutOfMemory

Answer (score 0):

You should probably simply raise the memory assigned to your program.
Check your -Xmx and -Xms properties.

Comment: Increasing memory everytime you get a OutOfMemory error is VERY bad practice.
Rather see whats using up the memory and try improve on that.
The only time you should increase memory, is when your apps memory footprint is larger than x percentage of total memory available...
By adding more memory before fixing memory hogs, you simple move the problem along until it's used up all memory again...

Comment: Not beeing able to know how big is user1648803's project, my answer was just to check the memory parameters. Spending time on finding which piece of code is responsible for the memory leack without at least having a glance on the memory properties is not a good idea, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CodePro Analytix](https://developers.google.com/java-dev-tools/codepro/doc/), to analyse your code against that code defect.

Answer (score 0):

How big is the dataset you are working with?
It looks like your query returns millions of records filling up memory...
Try using (if possible) a ResultSet or limiting the data, to restrict the amount of records in memory